# VUEJS ROUTER Refresh page before pushing it in dispatch action

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, lifecycle, page-refresh

I have a create user page. When I hit create user button it works fine, it creates the new user and redirect me to the page displaying all the users. But I noticed that, in order to see the last user (the one just created) here (in the page displaying all the users) I need to refresh the page.

Here the code, in createUser.vue:

```
methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      const userData = {
        username: this.form.username,
        email: this.form.email,
        password: this.form.password
      }
      try {
        this.userData = createUser(userData)
        this.$message('User created!')
        this.$router.push({
          path: '/users-list'
        })
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error in creating user: ', err)
      }
    }
  }
```

And in the users-list.vue:

```
created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('user/setUsers')
    const users = this.$store.getters.users
    this.users = users
    console.log("ALL USERS WITH GET PROFILE IN LISTA: ", users)
    console.log('store in lista utenti: ', this.$store.state)
    this.totalRows = this.users.length
  },
```

Is there a way to refresh the pushed route before it gets rendered?
Any lifecycle hooks I am missing?

Or maybe use a watch to spot change state of `users` (which in the store contains all the users created)?

I am currently checking for this solution as it seems to be the most appropriate to me, but if I am missing something about lifecycle hooks this option can be good to.

If anyone has an answer before me, please share :)
Thanks
x

**UPDATE**

I am back to this issue, I think the best way is the one indicated by @ambianBeing `createUser().then(res => /*do stuff*/)`  **do stuff = ?**
So, in the user module I created a new mutation and a new action (the one to be dispatched inside then() -before pushing the new route

```
.then(() => {
....
this.$store.dispatch('user/addUser')
this.$router.push({...})
})
```

).

The mutation, to kind of push the just created user to the users array, is:

```
ADD_USER: (state, user) => {
 state.users = [user, ...state.users]
},
```

And the action that commits this mutation is:

```
addUser({ commit }, users){
 commit('ADD_USER', users)
},
```

But the I get the just created user undefined, here the console.log:

```
ALL USERS WITH GET PROFILE IN USERS LIST:  (18) [undefined, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

I also tried user instead of users in the commit, but it doesn't work neither.

Anyone knows how to help?
Thanks

Comment: Is `createUser(userData)` resolving a promise or so? It might not be finished when the `created()` hook of `users-list.vue` is executed. You might also try to use `beforeMount` lifecycle hook.

Comment: Yes, axios always returns promises. Here the code of the api call: ```export function createUser(userData) {
  const bodyFormData = new FormData();
  bodyFormData.set('username', userData.username);
  bodyFormData.set('email', userData.email);
  bodyFormData.set('password', userData.password);
  return request({
    url: '/users/',
    method: 'post',
    data: bodyFormData
  })
}``` From what I read, beforeMount is not highly recommended, but I will try that. Thanks

Comment: I tried the beforeMount and looked better in the console: ```ALL USERS WITH GETTERS IN USERS_LIST:  (23) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},
SETUSERS RESPONSE:  (24) [{…}, {…},``` The last one is the response of the api call (correct with the last user in it), the first is taking the users state from the store, not yet updated.

Comment: @fdR Since `createUser` is an axios call/promise  why not update the store and push the route after it resolves `createUser().then(res => /*do stuff*/)`. Also on side note: if the dom directly depends on the data (fetch or store) **created hook** is the way to go.

Comment: @ambianBeing is right. However, you could also listen to changes using a `computed` property.

Comment: Thanks @ambianBeing, I get what you mean. ```createUser().then(res => /*do stuff*/)``` do stuff = ? Like pushing the created user to the array of objects saved in the store and then push the route?

Comment: I tried ```try {
        this.userData = createUser(userData).then(
          this.createdUser = userData
          
          //this.$store.getters.users.push(newUser)
        )
        console.log('newUser: ', createdUser)
        this.$message('Utente creato correttamente!')
        this.$router.push({
          path: '/users-list'
        })
      }``` but in the console I get: ```Error in creating user:  ReferenceError: createdUser is not defined
    at VueComponent.onSubmit```. I don't want to overcomplicate things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't passing a user object to the action …

```
this.$store.dispatch('user/addUser')
```

but the action expects to receive one:

```
addUser({ commit }, user){
 commit('ADD_USER', user)
}
```

N.B. The right action was the one passing user not users.

This solved the issue, and this was the way to do it. I guess. If someone thinks differently, please.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments, it seems like your promise won't resolve fast enough since it's an asynchronous call. There are multiple ways to resolve this. Here are 2.

**Use your returning promise**

@ambianBeing already mentioned that. You could set anything within the returning promise which eventually leads to the desired result.

**Use a computed property**

You could also use a `computed` property. Doing so, your component would re-render every time the state changes. So the following might resolve your problem.

```
computed: {
  users() {
    return this.$store.getters.users;
  }
}
```

Comment: I used computed property, I removed users[] from data and place inside computed as you suggested and it works, thank you! And thanks to @ambianBeing too x

Comment: I am actually getting this warning in the console: ```vue.runtime.esm.js:619 [Vue warn]: Computed property "users" was assigned to but it has no setter.```, even if the table is showing the just created user immediately. I updated the code as so: ```users() {
      get: () => this.$state.store.getters.users
      set: (users) => this.$state.commit('SET_USERS', users )
      return this.$store.getters.users
    }```

Comment: - In the store: ```setUsers({ commit, state }) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      getProfiles(state.users).then(response => {
        console.log('SETUSERS RESPONSE: ', response.results)
        commit('SET_USERS', response.results)
        resolve()
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log('error setting users: ', error)
        reject(error)
      })
    })
  },``` It should be right but the warning is still there. @ambianBeing see previous comment too

Comment: Since you're using VueX, keep things simple. Avoid mutating the store through a computed property. Instead, do any mutations within functions (methods) or lifecycle hooks. In your case that should lead to a lot better readable and maintainable code.

Comment: I understand, so how to get rid of this warning?